# Validity of the holographic principle

Tags: holographic-principle

Is the holographic principle applicable everywhere, e.g. is it possible to learn everything about any whatsoever volume of space everywhere in the universe from the boundary of it or does it have to be bounded by some special feature like an event horison? And do the same thing always apply in the reverse direction too, from the perspective of investigating from inside the same volume? Do these questions depend on the nature of space(time), it for example being de sitter one place or the other.
The question is intented as a generalization of
[Holographic principle "inside-out view"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76766/holographic-principle-inside-out-view)

Comment: Does this make sense in the context of a universe that has no boundary?

Comment: It would still be a finite volume outside the (say)  bubble I guess. The smaller the bubble would be though the more the "inside stretched horisont" would have to encode e.g. the more effective the scamblingmechanism/algoritm would have to be since more needs to be encoded; the planck volume would have to be able to handle the rest og the Universe minus it self.

Comment: That would be the ultimate consequence I suppose, global entanglement on the horizon.